# Is it safe to convert DateTime in time_t whithout error handling in C++ CLI?

Tags: c++, datetime, command-line-interface, time-t

I would like to use next code:

```
long long DateTimeToTimeT(System::DateTime dt)
{
    System::DateTime epoch(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    long long totalSeconds = (dt - epoch).TotalSeconds;

    return totalSeconds >= 0 ? totalSeconds : 0;
}
```

So question is: Is it exception safe or I should handle some errors here?

I mean: Is is safe to convert from `double` (which is TotalSeconds) to `long long` in such case?

Comment: what about when dt < epoch?  `DateTime` goes from 0001/01/01 to 9999/12/31, and it might be better to use `TimeSpan`

Comment: @cjb110, Actually... it IS used =)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is safe: the subtraction of two dates never throws (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1905yhe2(v=vs.110).aspx) since `TimeSpan` covers a much larger interval than valid dates.

Comment: Actually, when I was posting this question - I thought about problems with double - long long convert issues.

Comment: the internal representation of TimeSpan is Int64, so there is no conversion to or from double, but from Int64 to long long, that is the same type.